# Ajax parse xml file generated by php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to generate xml file from php for ajax response. but when i try to access it i got this error

---

XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity Location: moz-nullprincipal:{4f5dba1b-4a28-4fb0-8114-8c3c3f6ea485} Line Number 3, Column 1:

---

Comment: what does the XML look like? can you post a sample?

Comment: and the code you're using to receive and parse the data would be helpful, too.

Comment: Please add your code here so we could advise properly

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, I would assume you have leading whitespace in your XML, or your are simply outputting a completely broken XML format (no root or something).

If you are outputting XML, it would be advisable for you to use PHP's DOM Document and related methods rather than "manually" build it with some `echo`s or templates. Anytime you output a data format which has strict specifications (such as XML, JSON, etc) you should use mechanisms which properly build such formats (DOM Document, json_encode, etc).

Beyond this advice, we must see your XML generation code, and the output itself, before we can really tell you something specific.